# How can Reactstrap collapse open only one item?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I'm using reactstrap collapse for an accordion of FAQs.  However, I only want one open at a time. I've tried changing states of collapse, but nothing is working. I can open all of the items.  I also tried replacing it with the uncontrolled collapse so I don't have to manage state. Any thoughts?

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Col, Collapse } from 'reactstrap';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faChevronDown, faChevronUp } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg- 
icons';

class ListGroupCollapse extends React.Component {
static propTypes = {
    item: PropTypes.object,
};
state = {
    collapse: false,
    active: false,
};

toggle = () =>
    this.setState({
        collapse: !this.state.collapse,
        active: !this.state.active,
    });

render() {
    const item = this.props.item;
    return (
        <Col key={item.title}>
            <div
                className={this.state.active ? 'title active' : 'title'}
                onClick={this.toggle}
            >
                {item.title}
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={
                        this.state.active ? faChevronUp : faChevronDown
                    }
                />
            </div>
            <Collapse isOpen={this.state.collapse}>
                <div className="content">
                    <span
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                            __html: this.props.item.content,
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
            </Collapse>
        </Col>
    );
}
}

export default ListGroupCollapse;
```

Answer (score 2):

To open one collapse you should tie the collapse you want to open with some sort of id. So it knows what collapse to open.

```
this.state = {
  collapse: null
};

toggle = (id) => {
  if (!this.state.collapse || id !== this.state.collapse) {
    this.setState({
      collapse: id
    });
  } else if (this.state.collapse === id) {
      this.setState({ collapse: false })
  }
}

<Collapse isOpen={this.state.collapse === id}>
  <div className="content">
    <span
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: this.props.item.content,
      }}
    />
  </div>
</Collapse>
```

You just have to figure some system for your id's, generate these yourself or maybe you have them on your elements already, up to you. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer, You should make the collapse state an array of boolean values then change the value based on the index using the toggleCollapse function:

```
const [collapse, setCollapse] = useState([]);

const toggleCollapse = (index) => {
    let collapseCopy = [...collapse];
    collapseCopy[index] = !collapseCopy[index];
    setCollapse(collapseCopy);
}
```

JSX code inside map function:

```
<ListGroupItem onClick={() => toggleCollapse(index)} key={index}>
  <Collapse isOpen={collapse[index]}>
Hello world!
 </Collapse>
</ListGroupItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding isOpen = {true} property in your tag item ,hope this will work what you looking for.

Comment: It keeps the item open always. Toggle functionality stops working in this case. Any alternate?