# React Collapsible - Open One Accordion at time

Tags: reactjs, accordion

I am using the Collapsible npm package for React, and it solves most of my tasks, but there is no property that will allow only one active accordion to be opened at a time. I need logic that will close the previously opened accordion when the user clicks on a new one.
Below is my code of parent and child components.
Any help is welcome.

Child:

```
import Collapsible from 'react-collapsible';

const Accordion = ({
  open,
  trigger,
  triggerWhenOpen,
  children,
}) => {
  return (
    <Collapsible
      open={open}
      lazyRender={true}
      triggerTagName="div"
      trigger={trigger}
      triggerWhenOpen={triggerWhenOpen}
      className="mb-[30px]"
    >
      {children}
    </Collapsible>
  );
};

export default Accordion;
```

Parent:

```
 {/*Accordion mapping out */}
              {accordionArray.map((accName) => (
                <Accordion
                  open={accName.open}
                  trigger={accName.trigger}
                  triggerWhenOpen={accName.triggerWhenOpen}
                  key={accName + Math.Random()} //
                >
                  <AccordionContent
                    imgSrc={'/' + accName.imgSrc}
                    imgAlt={accName.imgAlt}
                  />
                </Accordion>
              ))}
```

Comment: Do you have accName.open property which is boolean and stores it is open or not ?

Comment: @Bhumit070 yes I have it, but it is built-in property of the Collapsible package. for the first accordion it is true, for the rest of them it is false, so when the user opens page for first time, first accordion is opened by default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can Reactstrap collapse open only one item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53635229/how-can-reactstrap-collapse-open-only-one-item)

Comment: can i put your code in codesndbox? it could be easier to fix it. https://codesandbox.io/s/del-y8gj0m

Answer (score 0):

You can open one collapsible at a time like this, this worked for me

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Collapsible from 'react-collapsible';

function App() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    return (
        <>
            <Collapsible trigger="Start here" open={count === 1} handleTriggerClick={() => setCount(1)}>
                <p>
                    This is the collapsible content. It can be any element or
                    React component you like.
                </p>
                <p>
                    It can even be another Collapsible component. Check out the
                    next section!
                </p>
            </Collapsible>
            <Collapsible trigger="Start here" open={count === 2} handleTriggerClick={() => setCount(2)}>
                <p>
                    This is the collapsible content. It can be any element or
                    React component you like.
                </p>
                <p>
                    It can even be another Collapsible component. Check out the
                    next section!
                </p>
            </Collapsible>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort this is very clean solution. Meanwhile, I gave up on the Collapsible package and made my own solution with useState and id.